# Masstransit - Blanket registration of generic consume filters for response messages?

Tags: masstransit

I need to configure a consume filter for all messages such that it

- processes all messages, including responses sent by a consumer using `context.RespondAsync`. Such response messages have no explicit consumers and are handled by MassTransit under the hood as part of Request-Response pattern, e.g. when calling `IRequestClient<TRequest>.GetResponse<TResponse>` method
- can access a strongly typed message object

It is possible to plug in an implementation of `IFilter<ConsumeContext>` to the pipeline. Such filter, while applying to responses (meeting requirement 1), gets a `ConsumeContext` passed to it (failing to meet requirement 2).
On the other hand, it is possible to plug in an implementation of `IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>`. Such filter gets a `ConsumeContext<T>` with `Message` property and can access the message, but needs to be added on a per-message basis for each message type.
`ConfigurationObserver` (https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/custom.html) automatically wires up a generic consume filter for all message types. However, it excludes response messages, which do not have user-defined consumers.

Is it possible to create such a filter without e.g. using marker interfaces for responses, scanning assemblies for marker interfaces and registering separate filters for each by hand?

We're using Masstransit v6.3.1.

PS as a side note it seems that `ClientRequestHandle`'s private `Response<T>` method takes an `Action<IHandlerConfigurator<T>> configure = null`, which could be utilised to add a custom filter specification to the response pipe, but this feature is not exposed publically.

Answer (score 0):

To meet this requirements, you should follow the same pattern that is used by message retry – using a configuration observer that is called as each message type is configured on every receive endpoint (including the bus endpoint, which is used by the request client to receive responses).

The best place to start in the MassTransit source is [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/MessageRetryConfigurationExtensions.cs#L20) at the configuration extension method.

The configuration observer has a method that is called once for each message type per receive endpoint, and it includes a generic argument for the message type allowing construction of a strongly-typed filter (`ConsumeContext<T>`) for each message type.

```
    public void MessageConfigured<TMessage>(IConsumePipeConfigurator configurator)
        where TMessage : class
    {
        var specification = new YourFilterPipeSpecification<TMessage>();

        configurator.AddPipeSpecification(specification);
    }
```

This will give you a filter per message type per receive endpoint, that you can then use to do thy bidding. There is no need for any marker interfaces, but you can optionally inspect `TMessage` and only add filters for specific types.

Comment: Thanks Chris. We have a configuration observer like your example, and we connect it to `IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator` [`Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg => Configure(cfg)`, where the `Configure` method calls extension that adds configuration observer and passes `cfg` for it to connect to],  but it only works for messages with have consumers.The `MessageConfigured` method is never called for response messages. Is it because we somehow fail to include "the bus receive endpoint"?

Comment: Where are those responses consumed? That's where the observer would find those messages.

Comment: Responses are received via `IResponseClient.GetResponse` method, they have no consumers, and if I understand correctly 'bus endpoint' is a private thing MT creates for itself and we don't have control over?

Comment: The bus endpoint is used by the request client, but the observer isn't called since it isn't _configured_ so I'm not sure how you'd know the response types being consumed.

Comment: You could just use an observer, for `PostConsume`, which is called after each message is consumed. You could use this if you aren't modifying the `ConsumeContext`.

Comment: Do we configure an endpoint by declaring a receive endpoint and associating a consumer with a response message ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222611/discussion-between-chris-patterson-and-aunaun).